# Python scripts don't work without python -m

Tags: python, macos

I'm extremely sorry for asking this question, but I'm absolutely clueless

I just migrated to a Mac, got python set up through brew, and everything works fine, except for the fact that I can't open up Jupyter notebooks, or access pip, without the

```
python3 -m pip
```

or

```
python3 -m jupyterlab
```

command

This has never happened to me before on Linux or on Windows, and I even double checked my path to make sure the python directories are included. Is it just that I have to create an alias, or am I missing something else here?

Comment: Do you have `$PYTHON_HOME/bin` in your path?

Comment: is that the /usr/local/bin/python or in the Library/python. Sorry, just confused with this library stuff as pip says that it installs it there

Comment: Try `which python3` and then see if the corresponding `bin` path is included in your path.

Comment: which python3 gives me /usr/local/bin/python3. my path has (/usr/local/bin) included in it..

Comment: @hoefling has said it all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have installed packages intact (e.g. you didn't remove the bin dir by accident), you can always find the binary path missing in your `PATH` env var by doing the following. Run

```
python3 -m pip show -f jupyterlab
```

This will output the list of files belonging to the installed package `jupyterlab`.

Now go through the list of files and look for the executable you're missing. Let this be `jupyter-lab` for the sake of example:

```
$ python -m pip show -f jupyterlab
Name: jupyterlab
...
Files:
../../../bin/jupyter-lab
...
```

Note the relative path. Now find the path in the `Location` line:

```
$ python -m pip show -f jupyterlab
Name: jupyterlab
...
Location: /tmp/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages
...
```

Resolve the path of the executable against the location to get the absolute path:

```
$ readlink -f /tmp/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/../../../bin/jupyter-lab
/tmp/myenv/bin/jupyter-lab
```

This is the path to your executable. Invoking it should work:

```
$ /tmp/myenv/bin/jupyter-lab -V
2.1.3
```

Now add the parent dir of the executable to `PATH` and check whether `jupyter-lab` is found now:

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:$(dirname /tmp/myenv/bin/jupyter-lab)
$ jupyter-lab -V
2.1.3
```

Once it works, you can persist the `PATH` changes to your shell profile (e.g. `~/.zprofile` for `zsh` on recent MacOS).

This approach is OS agnostic and will work the same on MacOS, Linux or Windows.

Answer (score 0):

what are the results of

```
echo $PATH
```

are the directories where the pip and jupyterlab scripts are stored in that PATH

If

```
which pip
```

or

```
which jupyterlab
```

come back with empty results then that is probably the case.  If you used the `--user` switch to install anything with pip (or python3 -m pip) then that is almost always the reason.  On OSX I think the default user location is `~/Libraries/bin` or `/Library/python3.8/site-packages`, on Linux it is always `~/.local/bin` or `~/.local/python3.8/site-packages`, so you may have to have a bit of rummage to find them.

Obviously change the python version to suit your situation.

Comment: which pip and which jupyterlab are blank as expected. strangely enough pip3 works. which python3 points to /usr/local/bin/python3

Comment: how did you install jupyter - with pip3 and sudo or with pip3 and the `--user` switch?  did you in fact install it? I apologise for not pointing out that any mention of pip should also encompass pip3

Comment: jupyter works perfectly with python3 -m jupyter lab, but I can't run it directly from the command line. I did not install it with the --user switch. My python seems to be in Library/Frameworks/Python.frameworks.... instead of /bin. I added the Library Frameworks to the path as well, but no luck

Comment: This is my path right now . Ill clean up the duplicates once this is over. /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/

Comment: according to this page https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/starting.html (extremely easy to find googling for `jupyterlab`) you have the wrong command.  what does `which jupyter` give you?

Comment: which jupyter is bank. Jupyter not found is the official message. python3 -m jupyter gives me the right output (i.e the Jupyter help menu)

Comment: the official python for macOS page has some stuff on the fact that there are somehow two different versions of python that macOS knows about, one which is supplied and managed by apple and one that is user based. (which Im guessing is the Library/Frameworks/Python.frameworks) path